# Is there a way to get all device's accessibility settings using UIAccessibility?

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

I need to delivery content to the user based on some accessibility settings state (on/off).

It seems that UIAccessibility doesn't expose all the settings.

For instance, I know the state of the Closed Captions setting by calling:

```swift
UIAccessibility.isClosedCaptioningEnabled
```

However, the Audio Description one is not exposed. I expected to have something like:

```swift
UIAccessibility.isAudioDescriptionEnabled
```

Best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every accessibility options defined in the settings are not necessary reachable.

I suggest to take a look at:

- [This list](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#accessibility-options) containing all the accessibility options with their notification name *(ObjC + Swift)* to be informed when their state changes hereunder:
  [image]
- This [detailed way](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/design/#accessibility-options) of activating each one of them on your device settings.

This list of accessibility options is exhaustive until new features are exposed by Apple itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this framework. It is pretty handy when it comes to accessibility settings in iOS. --> https://github.com/chrs1885/Capable